# Keep ordered array of dictionary values updated by index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a dictionary that's updated from another class. I have a property observer on the dictionary so I know when a value has been added or removed.

I create a sorted array based on the values of the dictionary. I need to keep this array updated and retain the index associated with the update for use with a UITableView. My UI is as such that a wholesale reloading of data isn't possible - I need to directly insert or remove rows based on what the update was.

I have simplified this into a playground:

```
func dictionaryUpdated() {

print("dictionary updated")
// Add or remove string at index depending on order.
}

var myDictionary : [Int:String] = ["Bob".hashValue:"Bob","Dave".hashValue:"Dave","Yoda".hashValue:"Yoda","Windu".hashValue:"Windu","Obi Wan".hashValue:"Obi Wan","Qui-gon".hashValue:"Qui-gon","Anakin".hashValue:"Anakin"] { didSet { dictionaryUpdated() } }

func addEntry(entry: String) {

myDictionary[entry.hashValue] = entry
}

func removeEntry(entry: String) {

myDictionary.removeValueForKey(entry.hashValue)
}

// sort the keys alphabetically while creating the array
var valuesArray = myDictionary.values.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
return lhs < rhs
}
```

I have tried using an NSMutableOrderedSet but the keys can only be Strings.

Comment: What's the question? You seem to have found a solution to your sorting problem, do you have some issues with that solution?

Comment: @Cristik yes - I need to keep the array updated when the property observer fires that a dictionary value has changed and I need to retain the index of the sorted update for use with a UITableView.

Comment: And doesn't the `valuesArray` do the trick? Or are you having problems to detect when the dictionary contents change?

Comment: @Cristik the values array does the trick the first time but as stated the dictionary is updated by another class, when that happens the values array needs to update but keep it's sort in tact and I need to know the index that was added or removed to update a table.

Comment: So what you need is the index within the sorted  array of the value added or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing around in playground. Can be much more elegant though...

```
var valuesArray: [String] = [] { didSet { valuesArray.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 } } }

func dictionaryUpdated(old: [Int: String]) {

    let added = myDictionary.count > old.count
    let item: [String] = added ? myDictionary.values.filter { !old.values.contains($0) } : old.values.filter { !myDictionary.values.contains($0) }

    valuesArray += item

    let index = valuesArray.indexOf(item[0])!

    print("item " + (added ? "added" : "removed") + ": \(item) at index \(index)")
}

var myDictionary: [Int: String] = ["Yoda".hashValue: "Yoda", "Windu".hashValue: "Windu", "Obi Wan".hashValue: "Obi Wan"] {
    didSet {
        dictionaryUpdated(oldValue)
    }
}

addEntry("Darth Vader")
print(valuesArray)
```

Output:

```
item added: ["Darth Vader"] at index 0
["Darth Vader", "Obi Wan", "Windu", "Yoda"]
```

Comment: This works really nicely, I've added a check on the added Bool, if it's false I then remove the item on the values array so it can be used as the tableview data source.

Comment: Yea I noticed it still needed some work, but you got the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the sorted array before and after the property change (which can be achieved via another instance variable), what you need to do is to compare the old and the new array, and detect which which indexes changed.

An elegant solution to this problem would be to add a `diff` method to the `Array` class which computes the difference. The method might look something like this:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func diff(other: [Element]) -> (added: [Int], deleted: [Int], moved: [(from: Int, to: Int)]) {
        var added: [Int] = []
        var deleted: [Int] = []
        var moved: [(from: Int, to: Int)] = []
        for (i, item) in enumerate() {
            if let j = other.indexOf({$0 == item}) {
                if i != j {
                    moved.append((from: i, to: j))
                }
            } else {
                deleted.append(i)
            }
        }
        for (i, item) in other.enumerate() {
            if indexOf({$0 == item}) == nil {
                added.append(i)
            }
        }
        return (added: added, deleted: deleted, moved: moved)
    }
}
```

You would then use like this: `valuesArray.diff(oldValuesArray)`.